# Overfitting with low test error

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have an ensemble of models that yields overfitting by some models by looking at the differentce between training and test error and also overfits in the combined ensemble of models providing a very small training error and an R2 of 1. In that circumstance I would expect the test part to have a poor classification error. However this is not the case yielding a low classification error. In what circumstances would this be posible. I have read that Overfitting may be used to provide diversity in ensembles provided the overfitted members have variety.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a specific programming question. It sounds like you're looking for statistical advice. This post seems more appropriate for [stats.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

After further discussions, it appears that the ensemble is heterogeneous in nature and the classification error is around 90% for Training Data (R2 is close to 1) and Testing data between 60-70%.  Under these conditions, I believe that it could come down to one of two possibilities:  (i) the representation of the training data for the problem, and (ii) the aggregation model for each of the classifiers to generate the overall result.

Comment: Thank you Mathew, the test error is arround 2x to 3x the training error, would not this be considered overfitting. In training the R2 is 1 and unfortunatedly the R2 for the test sample I can not extract. So in your opinión would not the difference between the train and test errors suggest overfitting?

Comment: You had stated that the training error was very low, so if the test error was also low, it doesn't sound like overfitting.  Could you provide some more details about the classification results?

Comment: Appologies the training error is small error and high R2 while the test R can not extract and the test error is 2x to 3x the training error.

Comment: What percentage correct for the Training Set and Test Set?

Comment: arround 90% for training and between 60% and 70% for test

Comment: Okay, that changes everything.  When you say very low, I was thinking more in the 95% + range, as you stated the test set error was still low, but it doesn't sound quite low there.  Might be a good idea to put the classification results in your original post :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61533/discussion-between-matthew-spencer-and-barnaby).

Comment: How can training and test error comparisons be indicative of overfitting if ensembles can achieve 100% of training accuracy without affecting test accuracy? See about the ensemble-razor paradox on page 82 here: [link](https://wiki.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2014-15/F/4412/_media/ensemble_data_mining.pdf)